# Check if generic parameter type derives from some class X

Tags: vb.net, generics, inheritance

What is the proper way of check if the type parameter is of type (or derives from) some type X? E.g.

```
Function MyFunc(Of T As BaseClass)() As T
  If TypeOf T Is GetType(ChildClass1) Then
    'Do something specific to ChildClass1
  End If

  'Do things common to all BaseClass objects
End Function
```

The above code doesn't compile, with or without `TypeOf`.

Comment: Try `If GetType(T) Is GetType(ChildClass1) Then`

Comment: @ZoharPeled: Apparently I missed something so straight-forward. Thanks for the input. I'll accept that as answer if you post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `TypeOf T` with `GetType(T)`.
Your code should look like this:

```
Function MyFunc(Of T As BaseClass)() As T
  If GetType(T) Is GetType(ChildClass1) Then
    'Do something specific to ChildClass1
  End If

  'Do things common to all BaseClass objects
End Function
```